# Sound volume on defined frequency (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, fft, aforge

I do not understand why the volume defined frequency is not as expected.

I send sounds to my microphone with a few specified frequencies in turn. I then do FFT of my microphone buffer. On exit of FFT, I have an array of complex numbers. To know the volume of sound on the defined frequency, I look at my array, the number of element in this array I get this way:

```
MyFrequency = n*SamplingRate/SizeOfArray.
```

Next, I get the magnitude of complex number

```
(sqrt(Re^2+Im^2)
```

If I'm right, this shows me the volume of sound on this frequency. But this value changes strongly, depending on the frequency. If I'm wrong, please explain to me what I need to do in order to correct my mistake. If I'm right, please explain me why this values change so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you applying a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) prior to the FFT ? If not then you will see the effects of [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage), and the magnitude at any given FFT bin will only be correct if the original frequency is an exact sub-multiple of the sample rate.

Comment: No, I dont use window function. If I use, for example, hanning window, I dont give this problem?

Comment: Yes - that's the whole point - you need a window function prior to the FFT. A "Hanning" (von Hann) window should be fine.